# Python : plots with different line styles having the same legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to create few plots and have hit a roadblock with specifying the legends. 
The plots have different line styles and the legend required for them should describe both or in other words a custom legend that can support both the plots.

```
plot(x1,y1,'o', x2,y2,'-')
```

I am trying to get a merged legend for both the plots.
It would be great, if someone has any pointers regarding this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If your plots styles just differ in marker and linestyle (as in your example) you could create a third plot mixing those styles and just put this into the legend. A simple example could look like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y1 = [1,2,3,4]
y2 = [3,2,5,1]
l1, = plt.plot(y1,'o',label=None)
l2, = plt.plot(y2,'-', color='r', label=None)
plt.plot(y1[0],'-o', color=l2.get_color(), markerfacecolor=l1.get_color(), label='My plots')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this creates this plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much this helps, but this is an example of what I did in a similar situation:

```
    import matplotlib.patches as patch

    red_patch = patch.Patch(color = "red", label = 'Plot 1')
    black_patch = patch.Patch(color = 'black', label = 'Plot 2')
    plt.legend(handles = [red_patch, black_patch], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```